# Manually Installing A New Kernel

Tags: linux, installation, kernel

For some reason, my kernel got uninstalled.

I have only file called "initrd.img-2.6.26-1-xen-amd64.bak" in my /boot folder. The only other thing is a 'grub' folder.

I booted into a rescue OS, but is there a way to install a kernel manually so that I can boot into my original OS again?

Can I just download a vmlinuz file into that folder and then fix my menu.lst?

Comment: What distribution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exact details depend on what your distribution is, so you need to add that detail to your question, but you should be able to:

1. mount your filesystems from an appropriate live/rescue CD
2. chroot so that your are using those filesystems in that terminal rather than the live CD's
3. ask your usual package management tools (yum/apt/what-ever) to reinstall the kernel package(s)

Assuming, of course, that the missing kernel is the only problem.