# Ubuntu 9.10: Freezes while installing software from Update Manager

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, installation, updates, freeze, xubuntu

Specs: Intel Pentium III @ 933 MHz, 512MB`PC133 SDRAM, 128MB GeForce FX5200, Maxtor 20.5GB IDE HDD, Ubuntu 9.10

Hi all, so I just installed Ubuntu 9.10 (from CD) on this machine after trying out Xubuntu. So, I did what I usually did, and [blacklisted a certain driver](http://tredosoft.com/rt2870_ubuntu) to make my wireless adapter work. After a restart, I went to the Update Manager to get all the updates and it finds 227 update packages.

So the first time I was installing updates, the screen turned off, due to power management settings and I was AFK while it was installing updates. Upon arriving home, I try moving my mouse, typing in the keyboard with no response. So I forced it to shut down and restarted. I get a [message](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/515950) and essentially I can't boot Ubuntu anymore.

So, I reinstall Ubuntu 9.10, following the same procedure as before, except that on first startup, I changed settings to keep my screen on. While doing software installation after updates were downloaded, Ubuntu eventually froze, while installing gcalctool. Mouse and keyboard were irresponsive, and I had no clue what was wrong. After a force reboot, I get the same message.

Why is Ubuntu freezing on me during updates installation?

**Edit 1:** I think that I may not be getting my wireless adapter to work properly, causing my machine to freeze. What I usually do it connect the adapter to USB after first startup, go to Terminal and type `sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`, add `blacklist rt2800usb` to the end, save, and restart. Wireless works upon restart... however, I think there is a more proper way to do it. **Seems like [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?s=445164085637c46196e3c68839c8e5eb&t=1342593) is the official way to get the wireless adapter running, will update.**

**Edit 2:** So I have set up my wireless adapter differently this time, using Ralink's driver (rt2870sta) rather than a community-written driver (rt2800usb). Once again, I will try to download the important security updates ONLY.

**Edit 3:** Important security updates successfully downloaded and installed. Now, where do I go from here? Install all recommended updates?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Wesley: the new title may reflect the current problem but it really doesn't match the description of your post.  i'm going to set the title back to the original; please post a new question asking about the proper way to configure the wireless adapter.  you're welcome to link back to this question to give people context.

Comment: re: edit3 -- at this point i'd unselect all the recommended updates and install a few at a time.  (like, select 1 or 2 packages; update mgr will autoselect their dependencies.  install the updates. select 1 or 2 more.  install.  lather, rinse, repeat.)  wasn't it the Nvidia driver update that seemed to be crashing?  leave that for last.

Comment: Alright. Will do. And yes, when I tried to activate the NVIDIA driver prior to installing the recommended updates and it froze. Would you think that the `nvidia-settings` update would allow me to activate the NVIDIA driver without freezing in the process?

Comment: Okay all updates have been successfully installed, including `nvidia common`. Now, which hardware driver should I activate?

Comment: I have the option of:
(1) NVIDIA accelerated graphics driver (version 173) [Recommended]
(2) NVIDIA accelerated graphics driver (version 96).

Latest Windows driver for the FX5200 is version 175.19, but when I activated that first driver before installing recommended updates last time, it froze. WHat should I do?

Comment: Well I can't wait... I'll be trying option 1 again.

Comment: Everything works now!

Comment: glad it worked, sorry i missed your recent updates.  my suspicion is it had trouble updating the kernel & the driver in one go, or something, but i couldn't give you a better guess without actually seeing the issue.

Comment: Ah darn... it's out again. Was installing Chrome, and the installation finished. Then it froze. No clue what's wrong now.

Comment: hrm.  i've been looking thru http://ubuntuforums.org and it seems like the nvidia 173 drivers should be working in ubuntu 9.10.  you should post over there; a threaded forum is better for this kind of back-n-forth than this site's Q-n-A format.  try sticking with the open-source drivers for a while to see if that avoids the freezes; that might help you narrow it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the freezes happen at other times as well or only during updates?  System freezes can be caused by wonky drivers and bad hardware, and can be difficult to diagnose.

Consider booting to the console and running your updates from there.

- Choose a "recovery mode" in the boot menu.  If your system is giving you that boot error, see if there's an older kernel version in the boot menu and use that.  (If you don't see the boot menu, hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> after your BIOS screen to make the menu appear.)
- When the system presents you with a recovery menu, choose the `netroot` option.

This gets you to a root prompt.  Be careful; you're the superuser now.

- Run `aptitude update` and let it finish.  This updates the cache of available packages.
- Run `aptitude full-upgrade`.  This will install all available package updates, so if your system freezes *are* due to the update itself, your system will freeze here.  If not, your system should be completely updated once this finishes.

Now try rebooting.

---

**If you get the same error at boot**, choose an older kernel from the boot menu and run this in a terminal:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

([source](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub/+question/89461)) (from [bug #1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/453678) and [bug #2](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/515950))

---

**If the system does freeze** during your console session upgrade, try upgrading a few packages at a time.  You can attempt this in the console (run the `aptitude` command by itself to get a console GUI; select a few packages to upgrade with <kbd>+</kbd>) or in Xwindows (by selecting only a few packages at a time in Update Manager).  If the update complains about missing dependencies, go ahead and install those too.

Comment: I'm sure the hardware is fine. I've used Memtest+ and ran the hard drive test from the Ubuntu disc. Will try other options when the opportunity arises.

Comment: Alright... only installing important security updates. Will install recommended updates if this works first...

Comment: Important security updates successful. Restart also successful. Will try installing recommended updates now.

Comment: @Wesley: i have a system that likes to freeze up under Ubuntu 9.04 for no apparent reason; mem & drive are both known good.  i've dealt with linux freezes before that turned out to be buggy video drivers (or maybe buggy video hardware, or both).  not my favorite task.  good luck with it!

Comment: @~quack: Exactly my problem now. It froze while trying to install the NVIDIA hardware drivers. After a force reboot, I am trying your recovery mode suggestion.

Comment: After trying to run aptitude update, I get something that says... "E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem." Then it appears that my wireless adapter is not working since I get a couple lines of "Could not resolve '[put website here]'" Then I get the "E: dpkg was interrupted..." message again, a line of "E: Couldn't rebuild package cache" and then the "E: dpkg was interrupted..." message again. I am not sure what's wrong, but I think I saw something about my w/less adapter having an error.

Comment: Looks like another reinstall right now. Trying to run it normally, I just get the logo and then a blank screen. Would taking the graphics card out and putting it back in change anything?

Comment: that sounds recoverable, but yeah a reinstall may be easier.  to recover, you'd need to boot to recovery mode, bring up the network (i'm failing on the commands ATM; has to do with *ifconfig* and *dhclient3* ), and then your aptitude commands should work.  alternately you could boot to the livecd, *chroot* into your system drive, and run commands there.  for that procedure see this: http://superuser.com/questions/111152/whats-the-proper-way-to-prepare-chroot-to-recover-a-broken-linux-installation

Comment: if you *do* go ahead with another reinstall, remember whether you enabled the official Nvidia drivers last time.  if so, *don't* enable them before the update this time.  if not, *do* enable them before the update.  the default driver is the open-source "nouveau" driver; the official driver must be enabled after installation.  sounds like one of those is breaking, and you should probably be trying the other.  (there are also several versions of the official driver, and one may work better with your hardware.  IIRC the GeForce5200 chip needs one of the older legacy drivers, not the newer ones.)

Comment: @Wesley: found those networking commands; if you can use wired ethernet temporarily, see this answer: http://superuser.com/questions/110913/repair-ubuntu-installation/110937#110937 ... for wireless i'm not sure, you can try replacing "eth0" with "wlan0" in those commands but i think something's missing...

Comment: Okay I am doing a reinstall, but I think the wireless driver may be the issue for now. I need to know the proper way to get my wireless adapter to work.

Comment: @Wesley: actually, your *blacklist* solution sounds reasonable to me, but i don't have the same hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Well, impossible to diagnose, but this seems like a bug in Ubuntu.

Your best bet is probably to report it to Ubuntu as a bug, with the exact steps to reproduce (as above). Then there's a fair chance it will get fixed.

Also, you could try redirecting the output of the update to a file (if this is possible in Update Manager), so you get a log that tells you where exactly the system crashed. That will help fixing the bug.

Also, try to use the hint from the bug report you linked, to get the system to boot even after the problem occured. Then you can probably collect more logs from the system.

Comment: I'm new to Ubuntu, so how would I redirect the update output to a file?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Ubuntu's Update Manager. You could use `apt-get`: `apt-get install ` then the list of packages to install. At the end append ` > /tmp/apt.out.txt` to get a log into a file.