# Fedora 12 hangs at boot

Tags: boot, fedora, nvidia-graphics-card

I'm kind of a beginner at Linux , I've installed an Nvidia driver with this command

```
# yum install akmod-nvidia
```

every thing went ok , but after reboot the system hangs right after

```
starting atd............ [ ok ]
```

and then I get a cursor "_" with nothing else happening!

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact problem yesterday, with Fed13 running in VMWare.  These details aren't important.  I was groaning at the thought it had something to do with X drivers or a bad kernel.  Ugh!  Luckily that wasn't the case.

Turned out to be the lack of a login manager (or whatever it's called these days) - gdm, kdm, or something to bring up a regular login prompt.  Somehow during a session of massive upgrades and removal of unneeded packages, I removed gdm.

Solution:  Alt-F2 (or other Fn) gave me a normal login, so I logged in as root, ran yum install kdm (or pick your favorite) and after that all was normal.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a more useful error in one of the other virtual terminals.  If you hold down the `<Alt>` key and press the function keys you can switch between them.

In order to fix this you're probably going to have to boot your system through another method, a common technique is to use a LiveCD (which may have been what you used to install in the first place, if not [download one now](http://fedoraproject.org/get-fedora)).

Once you've booted up with the LiveCD there's some more things you can do.  Easiest is to check the boot log - you should be able to see your installer partition on the desktop so double click on it and then look for `var/log` - the files of interest will be `messages` and perhaps `boot`, open them in gEdit and have a look for errors.

In order to resolve the error you may need to [edit the `xorg.conf`](http://www.linux.com/news/software/applications/8201-editing-basics-for-the-xorgconf-file) or you may need to [`chroot` into the installed system](https://superuser.com/questions/111152/whats-the-proper-way-to-prepare-chroot-to-recover-a-broken-linux-installation) and remove the `akmod-nvidia` package.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is answered in the RPM Fusion Howto:
http://rpmfusion.org/Howto/nVidia#head-205aab6f190d363e3915c0fa2e0681fc392aaeb6

I just installed the RPM Fusion package also - it's poor that there wasn't some documentation to mention the conflict with Nouveau when installing.