# How do I free some disk space so Ubuntu will boot again?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, ubuntu-9.04, disk-space

I have installed Windows and Ubuntu side by side.  I created a 10GB partition for the Ubuntu installation.  During the two months I've been using Ubuntu I have installed some software.  Now it's not starting.  When I boot up it says that there is no diskspace so it could not be started .

What can i do now?  When I boot up all I get is a black screen terminal with a `$`.
Please help me with a command to uninstall some programs and start using Ubuntu or any other way to get rid of this message.

Comment: Is it a full terminal emulator? if you can use apt-get, uninstalling programs will be trivial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Boot from the Live CD for a Graphical User Interface, its safer, and you'll know what you're deleting.
2. The LIVE CD is probably the disc you installed from.

[If you don't have the install disc]
Link to Live CD ISO: http://releases.ubuntu.com/karmic/ubuntu-9.10-desktop-i386.iso

Just as a side-note, you can use ANY Live CD ISO, which supports the ext4 file-system, if you're using it, if you're using ext3, any ISO will work, I'll recommend Damn Small Linux for the task. Link to DSL: http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/

Answer (score 1):

That black screen with a $ sign is the shell (command-line).

So it looks like there's not enough space to start the Gnome desktop, but at least you can start Ubuntu.

You should be able to remove some files at the command-line, until you have enough room to start the GUI.

The command-line package manager is **apt-get**, and you'd use it like this:

```
sudo apt-get remove PACKAGE-NAME
```

You can also list the installed packages with:

```
dpkg --list
```

If you're really not comfortable using the command-line (and it sounds like you're not), you should look for a 
Ubuntu Live CD; if you boot off this, you'll get a desktop, and you should be able to see the Ubuntu partition on the hard disk, and remove some files/packages from there.

Comment: to use a LiveCD to install/remove packages from a hard-drive installation, a user will need to use *chroot* (so his commands don't try to install/remove packages from the LiveCD environment).  see this excellent *chroot* tutorial: http://superuser.com/questions/111152/whats-the-proper-way-to-prepare-chroot-to-recover-a-broken-linux-installation