# Gnome wont start after removing "gnome-panel"

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, console, networkmanager, gnome-panel

After removing `gnome-panel`, Gnome doesn't start at all any more. I get a black screen and terminal upon turning the PC on.

It would seem no problem but the wireless network doesn't start too. So I have no internet connection to

```
apt-get install--reinstall
```

Comment: Maybe there is way to reinstall gnome from live cd?

Comment: sounds like you're booted into single-user recovery mode.  do you get a login prompt or are you logged in (as root) already?

Comment: you can use a livecd to recover; boot livecd; [chroot into the broken install](http://superuser.com/questions/111152/chroot-to-recover-a-broken-linux-installation); run your apt-get commands there.  the livecd gets the networking setup; chroot makes sure your apt-get commands fix the broken installation instead of operating on the livecd environment.

Comment: i had my login prompt disabled. Well I see my name in terminal. So I guess I am not logged in as root