# cdrom device not found during Linux installation on Macbook Pro

Tags: installation, macbook, multi-boot, debian, optical-drive

I'm trying to have a dual boot Debian / Mac OS X on my Macbook Pro.

I boot on the Debian install CD, the first steps are fine until "Detect and mount CD-ROM". It seems that the installer cannot find the cdrom device.

I ls-ed /dev and there is no "cdrom" in it.

Does anyone know about this problem ?

Comment: i'm not sure the MBP will be any different, but */dev/cdrom* is generally a symlink to the actual device.  try looking for */dev/hdX* (IDE/ATA devices) or */dev/srX* (SCSI/SATA devices) ... can you boot a LiveCD by any chance?  any LiveCD, eg Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

If the Debian install CD is giving you too much trouble, *but* you can boot to a Linux LiveCD (almost any will do), consider [installing Debian from Linux](http://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/apds03.html.en).

This is a very hands-on procedure, but if you're familiar with Linux already, it works well.  The link will give you all the details, but the procedural overview is:

1. Boot to a LiveCD (or a LiveUSB or any other Linux system);
2. Create partition(s), format filesystem(s);
3. Install & run *debootstrap* to install the base Debian system;
4. *chroot* into the new system (see the [SU *chroot* tutorial](https://superuser.com/questions/111152/whats-the-proper-way-to-prepare-chroot-to-recover-a-broken-linux-installation));
5. Configure the system (kernel, Apt, bootloader, ... told ya it's hands-on);
6. Install any other necessary packages.

Then reboot, repair anything that didn't get setup quite right, and install and configure additional packages as needed.