# mount dev, proc, sys in a chroot environment?

Tags: linux, debian, chroot

I'm trying to create a Linux image with custom picked packages.
<sub>What I'm trying to do is to hand craft the packages I'm going to use on an XO laptop, because compiling packages takes really long time on the real XO hardware, if I can build all the packages I need and just flash the image to the XO, I can save time and space.</sub>

When I tried to install some packages, it failed to configure due to missing the proc, sys, dev directories. So, I learned from other places that I need to "mount" the host proc, ... directories to my chroot environment.

I saw two syntax and am not sure which one to use.

In host machine:

```
  mount --bind /proc <chroot dir>/proc
```

and another syntax (in chroot environment):

```
  mount -t proc none /proc
```

Which one should I use, and what are the difference?

Comment: Beware: granting access to the disk devices means that you lose some of the benefits of '`chroot()`'.  In particular, the determined can read files outside of their section of the file system if you are not careful.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: that doesn't sound like an issue for what he is doing.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler a root user in a chroot can always escape the chroot anyway.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

For `/proc` and `/sys`, I suppose you could use either method. They are both special file systems so they can be recreated any number of times (the bind mount method uses the exact same mount as the host system, whereas the other method uses a new mount). I've always seen the bind mount recommended in guides, so I'd use that. As far as I know, there is no real important difference.

However, `/dev` is usually a tmpfs mount that is managed by udev, so it has to be the actual same file system as on the host machine. That means that you would need to use the bind mount method.

If this chroot is going to be around for awhile, you can put these entries in `/etc/fstab` on the host system to simplify things.

Comment: I would like to ask if it make sense to copy (bind) the proc/sys from host to some other machine ? Why should they match that machine ?

Comment: @ransh it make sens if you bind /proc to $chrootdir/proc , you will have possibility to handles proccess and whats going on inside /proc of both systems  from both systems ; e.g: from chroot you can check  if a program is running on the host ... etc

Comment: Maybe the `sys` `type` of file system appears (**today**) to not exist anymore?

Answer (score 165):

The [Arch Linux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Chroot#Using_chroot) suggests the following commands:

```
cd /mnt/arch # or where you are preparing the chroot dir
mount -t proc /proc proc/
mount --rbind /sys sys/
mount --rbind /dev dev/
```

Comment: They also seemed to work for me in ubuntu.

Comment: In my case (also Ubuntu) I needed a "mount -o bind /dev/pts dev/pts", too.

Comment: Please include the link to the source.

Comment: @styrofoamfly Added.

Comment: As of 2019, the ArchLinux wiki now does `--rbind` for `sys` and `dev`.

Comment: dont forget to unmount this when done, i had an issue with this on an alinux2.  also command on this was also `--rbind`.  Hmm, now i see @Saad mentioned this already, i had to test at it :-)
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61885/how-to-unmount-a-formerly-chrootd-filesystem

Comment: Relevant to @SaadMalik's comment that the ArchLinux wiki now does `--rbind` for `sys` and `dev`: [Difference between rbind and bind](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1122975/difference-between-rbind-and-bind-in-mounting)

Answer (score 16):

The [Gentoo Handbook](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/handbook-amd64.xml?full=1) specifically calls out these two commands for re-mounting /proc and /dev.  I've used them several times.

```
mount -t proc none /mnt/chroot/proc
mount -o bind /dev /mnt/chroot/dev
```

I suspect /sys is just a regular folder, so you should be able to make a hard link.

```
ln /sys /mnt/chroot/sys
```

Comment: You can't hardlink a directory (usually) like you suggest for /sys, and if you use a symlink it'll break as soon as you chroot.

Comment: They've added some new ones, based on systemd. Perhaps it's a good idea to add them.

Comment: `/sys` is not a _regular folder_, it's a `sysfs` mount.

Answer (score 3):

There are other pseudo filesystems and tmpfs locations.  This is on debian:

```
/dev/pts 
/run
/run/shm
/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_mist
/var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs
/proc/fs/nfsd
/proc/bus/usb
```

It should be okay to mount the `usbfs`, `rpc_pipefs` and `devpts` pseudo-filesystems from within the chroot.  I reccomend **not** binding `/proc` to the chroot's `/proc`, since the kernel has the concept of namespaces, and can actually put different things in the chroot's proc.

Update: according to [this mailing list thread](https://www.redhat.com/archives/libvir-list/2015-March/msg00520.html), /sys should not be bind mounted, especially if the chrooted processes is using its own network namespace.

It's a bad idea to mount the system's `/var` or `/run` onto the chroot, if the chroot has its own pid namespace.

Comment: Speculation? On superuser (and other stack-forums) it's usually better to hold off, or research and answer with linked sources, if you're unsure. This is to avoid risking spreading misguided hints. Sorry if disappoint and good luck!

Comment: @SimonB. I've added a link to a mailing list supporting the idea that /sys should not be bind mounted.

Comment: With pid namespace, you're talking about more advanced user namespace features we can find on modern linux kernels (i.e. the features "containers" are based on), while when we use the term chroot, we refer to the traditional file namespace change (and nothing else).

Answer (score 2):

It may be worth noting in this popular question, that Arch Linux has made a script [arch-chroot](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/any/arch-install-scripts/); download `arch-install-scripts-15-1-any.pkg.tar.xz`

This which takes care of various related problems both in **Arch-Linux** and **Manjaro** , where I used it successfully, too. Possibly more Arch-**derivates** like **Parabola** are compatible just as well.

While a simple standard `chroot` into a secondary Manjaro installation will not allow you to run

```
pacman --sync linux
```

(the silver bullet after a system crash), replacing the line with

```
arch-chroot /run/media/*YOURSELF*/manja-disk2
```

will enable you to fix your secondary Arch-derivate installation via

```
pacman --sync linux
```

like a charm. The bash script `arch-chroot` takes care of `/dev /sys /proc` and much more, which are left alone by the standard `chroot`.

see also: [Using arch-chroot](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Change_root#Using_arch-chroot)

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to reset the grub password on my laptop via a live USB, so I needed to use chroot as well.

The target system was Ubuntu 16.04 and I was working off an Elementary live USB. These commands worked for me to set up chroot:

```
mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /mnt
mount -t proc proc /mnt/proc
mount -t sysfs /sys /mnt/sys
mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
```

From here I was able to chroot in and `update-grub /dev/nvme0n1` to fix the password.

Before adding the last two `--bind` mounts, `update-grub` threw many errors about not finding devices but picked up the Linux partitions, missing the last Windows one. I guess the Windows part is just a quirk of my system, though.

Remember to `umount /mnt/dev/pts`, then `umount /mnt/dev` and the rest before unmounting `/mnt`.

For more context, [this chroot tip](https://superuser.com/a/111215/231154) might help.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to use a for loop:

```
cd /

for i in proc sys dev; do mount -o bind $i /folder/$i; done
```