# OpenBSD 'device not configured' error in chroot-ed environment

Tags: python, chroot, openbsd, cgi

I have asked this question on StackOverflow but given the [comment there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18819557/configuring-devices-in-chroot-environment-openbsd) it seems like it fits here better.

> This is almost certainly a system configuration issue—you didn't set up the jail right—rather than a Python one. You can test that very easily by just seeing what happens when you run, say, head -c16 /dev/urandom or dd if=/dev/urandom bs=16 count=1 from inside the jail. If you get the same error, go ask on SuperUser or ServerFault or another general Unix or OpenBSD forum. – abarnert

### Here's what I've done:

I want to run some cgi scripts (written in Python) on my OpenBSD server. Since the web-server on OpenBSD runs in a jail I recreated the whole folder structure (/bin /dev /usr /usr/local/lib etc. etc.) but I'm still getting '500 Server Internal Error' when I'm trying to import some Python modules that require access to /dev/urandom device.

I have created the device special files using mknod.

```
ls -la /dev/*random
ls -la /dev/{null,zero}
```

I got the following output

```
crw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   45,   3 Sep 13 11:09 /dev/arandom
crw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   45,   0 Jul 15 19:02 /dev/random
crw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   45,   1 Jul 15 19:02 /dev/srandom
crw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   45,   2 Jul 15 19:02 /dev/urandom
```

and

```
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel    2,   2 Sep 16 01:30 /dev/null
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel    2,  12 Jul 15 19:02 /dev/zero
```

So I executed the following commands in the /var/www/dev folder (OpenBSD web-server runs in chroot -u www /var/www)

```
mknod -m 666 null c 2 2
mknod -m 666 zero c 2 12
mknod -m 644 random 45 0
mknod -m 644 srandom 45 1
mknod -m 644 urandom 45 2
mknod -m 644 arandom 45 3
```

However, Python still reports that the

```
OSError: [Errno 6] Device not configured '/dev/urandom'
```

The same code works fine in a non-chroot-ed environment.

```
import os
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()
```

Given the advice on StackOverflow I run

```
chroot -u www /var/www dd if=/dev/urandom bs=16 count=1
```

and got the same result

```
dd: /dev/urandom: Device not configured
```

i.e. it's definitely a config error. Can anyone shed some light where I may be making a mistake? Any help would be truly appreciated!

Comment: Have you mounted /dev to your chroot environment using `mount -o bind`?  [This answer](http://superuser.com/a/165118/156446) has a concise overview of why this is needed for `dev`

Comment: I tried doing that but OpenBSD does not have the option `bind`... Is there an equivalent? I read around and apparently one could do that with `mount_null` but that has been removed... Can I use `mount -o sync /dev` instead?

Comment: I found the culprit (partially...). It is not necessary to mount the device. In addition, as I mentioned before, in OpenBSD I couldn't find `mount -o bind` equivalent. Following the advice from comments from [this site](http://synacks.blogspot.com.au/2009/01/django-on-openbsd.html) it is enough to mknod (as I have done earlier) and remove `nodev` from `/etc/fstab` where the system mounts `\var`. Although my script still does not work it no longer reports **Device not configured**

Comment: Just to finish off -- the _hashlib.so (called from `import cgitb`) depends on a shared library libcrypto.so. That was the problem with my script not running... Thanks all for your help!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted, sorry if I led you down a linux-specific rabbit hole :) You can post that as an answer, it will let you accept it after a day or so I believe.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Glad it finally works?

Answer (score 3):

**I found the culprit.**

Following the advice from the comments section of [this site](http://synacks.blogspot.com.au/2009/01/django-on-openbsd.html) it is enough to mknod (as I have done earlier) and remove `nodev` from `/etc/fstab` where the system mounts `/var`. This removes the 'no-devices' allowed flag in `/var`.

To make my script run I finally had to copy all the shared objects that Python's `cgitb` module (well, in fact, `_hashlib.so`) depends on -- namely `libcrypto.so`.

To find what your `_hashlib.so` depends on run `ldd _hashlib.so` -- mine is located in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_hashlib.so`. Note -- you will find this library if you have OpenSSL installed on your system. If you don't, `_hashlib.so` loads e.g. `_md5.so` etc. that can only be find if you

1. Don't have OpenSSL
2. Configured and built Python with `--with-pydebug` flag (check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590242/sha-import-in-python-hashlib) for more details)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

check `/etc/fstab`. I had `nodev` in the mount point and that prevented my chroot'd command from running properly.

Answer (score -1):

I Had similar problem running Django in FreeBSD and OPENBSD.
My problem was that the gunicorn process was running as root while the scripts were in outher users home/dir.

tl;dr -> check if the process is running with the right user