# Purging and reinstalling Grub on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: ubuntu, installation, grub

I'm having a grub issue here. I have Windows 7 on `sda`. On `sdb` I have 3 partitions which I used on my old pc where:

- one partition for Ubuntu 11.10
- another for Windows XP
- the third partition I keep some mixed files (Movies, music, etc.).

I made a usb live install and I successfully installed ubuntu 12.10 on the partition where it used to be installed Windows XP (`sdb1`). Problem is that when I choose to boot to this HDD, it shows me the "old" grub for my old system, it even starts loading ubuntu 11.10 and then crashs.

I already tried to run `Boot-Repair` to purge and reinstall grub but I keep getting a `dpkg error` that won't let it finish. Anyone could give me some hints here?

Comment: Since I was going to recommend `boot-repair`, what error are you getting?

Comment: One does not simply... purge GRUB.

Comment: dpkg-error detected. Please open a terminal then type (or copy-paste) the following command:
sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/sdb1" dpkg --configure -a
When I type that in terminal, it opens configuring grub-pc but there is no devices listed just an ok button
Then close this window.

Answer (score 0):

You should boot into a Linux live session and reinstall GRUB manually. Have a look at [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Installing.2BAC8-Reinstalling.2BAC8-Moving_GRUB2) for example.

The basic procedure involves booting into the live sesion, mounting your `/` partition, using `chroot` to set it as `/root/` and then installing GRUB.

There is a very good answer on how to use `chroot` [here](https://superuser.com/a/111215/151431).

The Ubuntu (will apply to any Linux really) instructions on reinstalling GRUB are [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows) or [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Fixing_a_Broken_System).