# How can I triple boot from two hard drives?

Tags: windows, multi-boot, fedora, grub2

Please excuse the length on the question; this is a bit tricky to explain.

I have two SATA hard drives in my HP dc7100CMT, and their sizes are 500GB and 160GB. In the larger drive, I have Windows XP Pro 64-bit and Windows 7 Pro 64-bit, in two partitions respectively.

In the second (160GB) drive, I installed Fedora 20 64-bit and formatted it into four partitions: boot, data, swap, and root (in that order). I also installed the GRUB2 boot-loader to the "/boot" partition. However, when I turn on my PC, after the POST messages clear, the system boots into the first hard drive, as it has always done before. (Windows 7's boot loader is called and asks me If I want to load XP or 7 - This behavior should have changed after installing Linux.)

When I check my BIOS, I have no options of changing the boot device (For multiple SATA drives, it starts the drive on SATA-0 by default and that cannot be changed). The other constraint is that I cannot change either of the Windows partitions on the first drive (and the drive has no unallocated space to install a new partition).

This leaves me with two options:

1. Install GRUB2 to my Windows drive (preferred - if possible)
2. Physically change the drive order connected to the motherboard (really want to avoid doing this)

My question is, how can I try option 1 (or something similar)? If not, is there another way?

Comment: Install the operating systems in order.  If you want Windows XP, Linux, and Windows 7.  Install them in that order.  After you install the last operating system you will have to "repair" Grub.

Comment: @Ramhound I said I can't do that; I cannot reinstall Windows - that's the constraint. Plus, I DID install them in the order I want, with Linux on a separate drive. It's just the bootloader I CAN change.

Comment: You didn't but limits on what your options were, you want to acheieve option 1, I provided you a way to do that.

Comment: @Ramhound I appreciate the help, but I needed something like terdon's answer since overwriting the bootloader is what I intended to accomplish; sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: It's bit to late to make yourself clear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to boot using the Fedora install CD and from there install GRUB to the Windows drive. **This will delete the Windows bootloader** but you will still be able to load Windows through grub.

When you've booted into the Fedora live session, you will have to mount your local drives and set up a `chroot` environment. There is a very good answer on how to use `chroot` [here](https://superuser.com/a/111215/151431) but the basic procedure is:

1. Create the necessary directories

   ```
   sudo mkdir /mnt/boot /mnt/root
   ```
2. Mount your local Linux system (change the device names accordingly)

   ```
   sudo mount /dev/sdb3 /mnt/       ## the / partition
   sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/boot   ## the /boot partition
   sudo mount -t proc proc /mnt/proc
   sudo mount -t sysfs sys /mnt/sys
   sudo mount -o bind /dev /mnt/dev
   ```
3. Set up the `chroot`

   ```
   sudo chroot /mnt
   ```

Now, create grub's configuration file. If you're using a Red Hat-based system (like Fedora) run

```
sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

For Debian-based systems, run

```
sudo update-grub
```

That's just a shell script that runs the `grub2-mkconfig` command above but also includes `set -e` for safety (it will exit immediately on any errors).

Make sure the output of that command lists both your Windows systems. There should be lines like

```
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda1
Found Windows XP (loader) on /dev/sda2
```

If grub has seen your other OSs correctly, install it to your 1st hard drive. For Red Hat based systems run:

```
sudo grub2-install /dev/sda
```

And for Debian based:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

Finally, exit `chroot` and reboot:

```
exit
sudo reboot
```

Comment: I tried your answer, however `sudo update-grub` says "update-grub" is not valid. I tried with "update-grub2", but that was also invalid.

Comment: @abckookooman sorry, I had forgotten you mentioned Fedora. Try the updated answer.

Comment: +1 Your answer worked like a charm. However, I only had to use the last two lines, since fedora automatically sets up chroot ;)
However, GRUB loads windows 7 bootloader. If I have to access windows, I have to go through GRUB and windows bootloader...is there a simple way to add an entry in grub.cfg?

Comment: @abckookooman probably yes, but please post a new question for follow up issues.

Comment: Damn your good.