# Ubuntu chroot using different internet connection

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, ubuntu-9.04

When I boot from Ubuntu 9.04 liveCD, I can use my wireless internet. I have no idea how this tool is called, but it is in the upper right corner, lets me choose among detected wireless networks, enter key, etc.

When I use apt-get in terminal (being in LiveCD) it's all OK, internet connection works and aptitude downloads everything it needs.

**Is there a way to keep using this connection even after chrooting into somewhere else?**

I need to chroot to my "real" Ubuntu install in order to fix it ([got messed up](https://superuser.com/questions/110913/repair-ubuntu-installation)). So I do **chroot /media/disk** and from there on I have no internet connection in terminal. So if I use apt-get install ubuntu-desktop, apt-get complains about not being able to resolve ubuntu http repository urls or something like that. Exactly as if I boot into real, messed up Ubuntu install I want to fix, because it has no working internet either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just added a detailed chroot tutorial [here](https://superuser.com/questions/111152). One thing you should do is copy your /etc/resolv.conf file over before doing the chroot. That may be all you need to fix this.

Comment: everything's going according to plan. *muahahahahaha!*

Comment: (I was confused by the comment until I noticed quack started the community wiki question I linked to.)

Comment: (and i found it odd that there was suddenly another *chroot* question until i realized... it was posted by the author of one of the questions that prompted ... my CW *chroot* question! ha!)

Comment: :)) Thanks a lot guys, gonna try that. Finally got time to work with this again.

Comment: Copying /etc/resolv.conf did the trick!